# Cannot find class org.alfresco.web.config.WebClientConfigBootstrap in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-maven

Not build app for Alfresco 5.2 in ide Eclipse.

How to fix?

Error log after attempting to build the application:

```
FAILURE! - in com.eisenvault.demoamp.test.DemoComponentTest
testChildNodesCount(com.eisenvault.demoamp.test.DemoComponentTest)  Time elapsed: 12.924 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.alfresco.web.config.WebClientConfigBootstrap] for bean with name 'ev-esign-repo_pdftoolkit-esign-configBootstrap' defined in file [C:\Users\MIR-IT\Documents\eisenvault-esign-master\eisenvault-esign-master\ev-esign-repo\target\test-classes\alfresco\module\org.alfresco.extension.addimages\module-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.alfresco.web.config.WebClientConfigBootstrap
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.alfresco.web.config.WebClientConfigBootstrap
```

Why then the program can not find org.alfresco.web.config.WebClientConfigBootstrap

How to connect Class org.alfresco.web.config.WebClientConfigBootstrap?

File module-context.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Bean action definitions -->
    <import resource="classpath:alfresco/module/org.alfresco.extension.addimages/context/alfresco-pdf-addimages-context.xml" />

    <!--  iText transformers -->
    <import resource="classpath:alfresco/module/org.alfresco.extension.addimages/context/service-context.xml" />

    <!-- load the custom content model -->
    <bean id="ev-esign-repo_pdftoolkit-esign-model" parent="dictionaryModelBootstrap" depends-on="dictionaryBootstrap">
        <property name="models">
            <list>
                <value>alfresco/module/org.alfresco.extension.addimages/model/addImagesModel1.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Load the UI customizations -->
    <bean id="ev-esign-repo_pdftoolkit-esign-configBootstrap" class="org.alfresco.web.config.WebClientConfigBootstrap"
        init-method="init">
        <property name="configs">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:alfresco/module/org.alfresco.extension.addimages/ui/web-client-config-custom.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell from the code, but it appears you are trying to do something with the web client from the repo (alfresco.war) context. Anything having to do with the web client should be in a Share (share.war) context.

The only exception to this would be if you were trying to do something with the ancient Explorer client, but that web client isn't available in 5.2.